# Listview not displaying 2 items in a row even though GroupItemCount is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am still new in asp.net c# and want to display a listview with 2 items in a row. However, the listview is not displayed with 2 items in a row even though I use GroupItemCount. Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvClientFacility" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyName="facility_id" GroupItemCount="2" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceholder1" runat="server" /> 
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <GroupTemplate> 
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </GroupTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <a class="facility" href="clientReservation.aspx?Id=<%# Eval("facility_id")%>">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="250px" ImageUrl='<%#"data:img/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("facility_image"))%>' /> 
        <div class="facilityName"><%# Eval("facility_name")%></div> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" PostBackUrl= '<%# "clientReservation.aspx?facility_id=" + Eval("facility_id") %>' runat="server" Text="Book Now"/>
        <div class="ClientFacilityDescription"><%# Eval("facility_description")%></div>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```